# Using wrapper classes to swap variables of a class

Tags: java, object, swap

This is a program of geeksforgeeks.org. I am not able to understand the use of wrappper class. Can anyone explain this code in detail.
It is a program to swap two objects so that the variables get swapped. used when we dont know the number and type of variables in classes.
I have provided the link for further reading.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-exchange-objects-java/

```
// A Java program to demonstrate that we can use wrapper
// classes to swap to objects

// A car with model and no.
class Car
{
    int model, no;

    // Constructor
    Car(int model, int no)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.no = no;
    }

    // Utility method to print object details
    void print()
    {
        System.out.println("no = " + no + 
                           ", model = " + model);
    }
}

// A Wrapper over class that is used for swapping
class CarWrapper
{
   Car c;

   // Constructor
   CarWrapper(Car c)   {this.c = c;}
}

// A Class that use Car and swaps objects of Car
// using CarWrapper
class Main
{
    // This method swaps car objects in wrappers
    // cw1 and cw2
    public static void swap(CarWrapper cw1, 
                            CarWrapper cw2)
    {
        Car temp = cw1.c;
        cw1.c = cw2.c;
        cw2.c = temp;
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Car c1 = new Car(101, 1);
        Car c2 = new Car(202, 2);
        CarWrapper cw1 = new CarWrapper(c1);
        CarWrapper cw2 = new CarWrapper(c2);
        swap(cw1, cw2);
        cw1.c.print();
        cw2.c.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: The link you posted explains it in every detail.  Have you actually try all the code their one step at a time?

Comment: Which part of the linked page don't you understand?

Comment: `CarWrapper` class holds reference to class `Car c`. When you create objects you have two `CarWrapper` and two `Car` objects. In `swap` method you assign `Car c` object of `CarWrapper cw1` to `Car c` of `CarWrapper cw2` and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

In Java everything is passed by value , in case of objects , its location is passed by value which means we get reference to the object. Now why are we using wrapper classes here. In the first code , we know how many members are there so we just simply swap the members of the classes. What if we don't know or when there are a lot of member variables. The second example explains this. We are only swapping the references of the objects . **And in Java this type of changes are not reflected back ,i.e, assigning a reference of an object to other object** . **However,changes are reflected if we make changes to these object's member variables**. In the third code example , we are firstly creating Car objects and then CarWrapper which has a member of type Car (which will contain location of the Car object). Now, when we are calling the swap method we are passing location of the two CarWrapper objects and then we are swapping the members of the CarWrapper objects by swapping the location inside the members , so now they point to the swapped location .
`public static void swap(CarWrapper cw1, 
                            CarWrapper cw2)
    {
        Car temp = cw1.c;
        cw1.c = cw2.c;//here changing location to Car object2(c2)
        cw2.c = temp;//here changing location to Car object1(c1)
    }`